# Can I create widgets for Notification Center in iOS without jailbreak?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I want to create a widget in NC with some toggles for airplane, wifi, bluetooth, etc. without jailbreak, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but no, you cant do that. :)